# WebDAV or SFTP to access my Cynology NAS from the internet?

Tags: nas, file-transfer, sftp, webdav

What is the best way to access my file in a NAS from the internet?

Why use WebDAV over SFTP?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216884/which-file-access-is-the-best-webdav-or-ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216884/which-file-access-is-the-best-webdav-or-ftp)

WebDAV has some advantages over FTP. But, depending on yout setup *"SFTP is more feature-rich than WebDAV and SFTP is a protocol to access remote file systems, while WebDAV was designed with abstraction in mind (WebDAV was for "documents", while SFTP is for files and directories). SFTP has all benefits mentioned above for WebDAV and is more popular among both admins and developers."*